# Is Popc a native instruction in Tegra Jetson TK1?

Tags: cuda

Jetson has 3.2 capability.

Popc is very fast if native, i.e. implemented as an Assembler instruction instead of written in C.

I want to know whether or not popc is native in Jetson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POPC`is [listed](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#kepler) in the native instruction set for the Kepler architecture. I would, therefore, assume it is implemented in hardware or microcode. Whether that implies it is fast is a separate question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link.  I couldn't find it by myself.  And you're right about the speed.  I think (hope) popc's hardware implementation is fast in comparison with its software implementation, because it's very easy and cheap to do so.

Comment: @AlejandroSilvestri I don't know if you are aware of it, there is an [intrinsic `__popc`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_g43c9c7d2b9ebf202ff1ef5769989be46.html) which you can use in your code without having to use assembly.

Comment: @ m.s. , thank you, I already knew this, I use __popcll which works on 64 bits, because I have to "population count" a 256 bits long integer.  BTW, I considering the use of popc for stream compaction as in this paper: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/streamcompaction.pdf, which don't perform well en GT200 because it lacks of native popc, but I hope will work fine on Jetson.